# Adding data to a listbox?

Tags: c#

I've been stuck on this for a while now and i was wondering if there was a way to add Data to a listbox through a textbox inside a form. I have a button which leads to a seperate form which asks for the user to input data for that listbox.

this is in c# Visual studio 2012

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: I suggested an answer below if the elements are on the same form. If not can you elaborate on the issue and provide the code of any attempt you've made so far?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are on the same Form then this will add when the `TextBox` loses focus:

```
private void textBox_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(((TextBox)sender).Text);
}
```

If they're not you'll need an intermediary class to hold the data entered into the `TextBox` and then when the second form loads retrieve the data from the data class and load it into the `ListBox`:

```
private void textBox_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _inMemoryDatabase.Add(((TextBox)sender).Text);
}

private void form2_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var item in _inMemoryDatabase.GetData())
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: `I have a button which leads to a seperate form`  The OP didn't show us any code, but I think this is the part that's probably confusing them.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. I'll show you one simple method.

[image]

Here I have two forms

1. Name List (With a listbox and button)
2. Form_TakingValue (with a textbox and button)

You can pass this listBox as parameter to the form_takingValue, so that any changes can be done within the second form.

**Name List Form Code**

```
public partial class NameList : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form_TakingValue(listBox1).ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Form_TakingValue Code**

```
public partial class Form_TakingValue : Form
{
    ListBox listBox;
    public Form_TakingValue()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form_TakingValue(ListBox lBox)  // -> Overloaded function for our needs
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox = lBox;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(txtName.Text); // this listBox belongs to the first form and we are making changes to it from here..
        Close();
    }
}
```